# Parse Hash and array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting the following hash from an api and need to parse it so that I can access the field `name` with value `Southern Company (SO).` What's confusing me is that looks like an array is built inside the hash and I'm having difficulties parsing it.

```
 #<OmniAuth::AuthHash _total=1 values=[#<OmniAuth::AuthHash company=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash id=157357 industry="Utilities" name="Southern Company (SO)" size="10,001+ employees" ticker="SCE" type="Public Company"> id=695794923 isCurrent=true startDate=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash month=1 year=2015> summary="•\tDeveloper " title="Jr.Developer">]>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried?:

```
response['values'][0]['company']['name']
```